# excel write to the same folder as m file

Tags: matlab

I have an m file which creates an excel file using `xlswrite`.  If I do not specify the the folder for the xls to be output to, the default is the users folder.  I would prefer that it goes to the same folder as the m file.  Is there a way to generalize this without explicitly entering the m file location?  I plan on distributing this m file and not everyone will keep their m files in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the path where running m-file is stored, check out:

```
help mfilename
help fileparts
```

Comment: Also, `help fullfile` for constructing the path argument for `xlswrite`

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use the current working folder as the save location.  This is whatever the "current directory" is in the matlab window.

You can access it using the command `pwd`.  This returns a string that is the path to the directory.

Then append `\filename.ext` to it and you'll be good to go!

Comment: the current working folder might not be the folder of the script

Comment: Generally speaking though, if you're running the m-file from the command line you're most likely going to have that directory set as your current directory.  I know you can run it without that being the case though.  This merely gives the OP another option to consider.

Comment: Not if you distribute it as a toolbox as OP is suggesting. Besides, if you don't give a full path, the current working folder is used anyways as destination for saving files